# How to hide title app when display a layout?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide, fullscreen

I have a layout A. When i enter to layout A, i want title app or actionbar will be hide.
i have searched in Google.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Fullscreen">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

But it must do in AndroidManifest.xml 
 (My app have many screen, and just only layout A, action bar will hide.)

So, i find a way which can set up it into file layout A?
How can i do that ?

Comment: layout A is load in to which activity? give fullscreen theme to it activity only.

Answer (score 0):

> use **getSupportActionBar().hide();** to hide your action bar programtically

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

> if you want fullscreen activity than use below code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

> Or you can do it via your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```